# How do I get my google chrome extension to interact with pages outside the extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I've built the main functionality for an extension already, and have it uploaded as a web page on my server.  I'd like to have it interact with any page a visitor goes to though and not just my page on the server.  It's just the HTML/CSS/Javascript and jQuery.

I've been reading the documentation, and it says/implies I need to use a content script.  I do have this script included as a content script as well though, however I'm probably doing it wrong.  Mainly looking for some guidance/direction as to where to go on this.

The extension is to be one that removes all images from a page.

```
The site is http://199.127.226.221/testsites/chromeapp/

This is the manifest file: http://199.127.226.221/testsites/chromeapp/manifest.json
This is the .crx file: http://199.127.226.221/testsites/chromeapp/chromeapp3.crx
```

Comment: I know that, I posted the links to my server in order to make it easy for the community to view the individual HTML and Javascript/jQuery files. 

What I meant, is that after I pack this into an extension (.crx), how do I get the extension to work on any page for any website?

I've tested a local .crx file of this, but right now it only works on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You should supply the extension as a .crx file.
Also it seems you should specify desired urls for content scripts in permissions of manifest

Comment: Updated with the .crx file now :-)